# Is it normal to have a sharp increase in validation error when using 10% of the data instead of something like 20-30%?

Tags: classification, cross-validation, train-test-split

Scenario:

I'm training a relatively simple neural network to classify pairs of tabular datapoints (~150k), lets say drugs and diseases, whether they are related (positive) or not (negative). As I only have a list of related pairs, I first split my data to train and test sets. Then, for each pair in my train set, I randomly sample a disease for each drug in a manner that the new pairs are not present in the training set, and the training set only, so to avoid data leak. This negative sampling is also done in the test set, but there the new negative pairs are checked against both the train and the test sets. Result is, around 300k pairs with 50/50 positive-negative split. Additionally, the features of the pairs are standardized, but once again, the test set is standardized with the mean and variance of the train set to avoid data leak.

Problem:

The model performed quite good with a 0.7/0.3 train-test split, but when I tried 0.9/0.1 its performance dropped off sharply. I've run it multiple times, it isn't just a result of an accidental bad split. Moreover, the training errors remained about the same in both splits. Is this a normal phenomenon? Or is there something I did wrong?

Edit:

Training the very same model for 10 epochs

0.6/0.4 split (even better performing than the 0.7/0.3)

train_loss=0.3715, train_accuracy=0.8456, train_auroc=0.9147, train_auprc=0.9089
test_loss=0.3803, test_accuracy=0.8374, test_auroc=0.9099, test_auprc=0.9139

0.9/0.1 split

train_loss=0.3343, train_accuracy=0.8620, train_auroc=0.9311, train_auprc=0.9310
test_loss=0.4557, test_accuracy=0.7943, test_auroc=0.8779, test_auprc=0.8837

There are batch norm and dropout layers in the network to improve generalization.

Comment: It is normal to observe such changes in performance. They are endemic to any approximating, iterative algorithmic method. That said, it would help if you were to post the results for the performance and error metrics wrt these splits, just to give us some idea of how dramatic the decline really is.

Comment: @MikeHunter edited with the results. As I have tested, the difference can be made even more drastic with for example 0.5/0.5 split vs 0.99/0.01. Looking at the losses, can it be that the model quickly overfits when enough training data is present? Perhaps the low variability of drugs (~2500) among the datapairs when compared to the entire set of paris (~300k)?

Comment: Have you put confidence intervals around the estimates? If so, are the results within, say, 95% CIs? Also, are the split samples strictly controlled for? In other words, are the same entities in each and every epoch? If not, some of the variability is attributable to that lack of control.

Comment: @MikeHunter I've not yet check CIs, but the train-test data remains the same for the corresponding training across all epochs, only the train is reshuffled (not resampled) at the start of each.